# Java FX - BarChart dynamically added content destroys the layout

Tags: java, layout, javafx, bar-chart

I'm struggeling with the Java FX BarChart.. My own implementation of the chart is a class that extends the Java FX GridPane and holds a BarChart as a member variable.
If I initialize the whole thing everything works perfect, but if I change the data dynamically (add one or remove one data) the layout will be destroyed.
Speaking in pictures this means: (sorry i can't upload picture at the moment)

[pic1 - initialization](http://i58.tinypic.com/33uriwm.png)

[after adding one element](http://i58.tinypic.com/14tvwqg.png)

So the 1st pictures shows the chart after initalization, the 2nd after one element has been added and after deleting one element the categories aren't shown anymore. (I Ccan't upload a picture of this)

So here's my code:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import someCompanyThings.IMyBarChart;
import someCompanyThings.LocaleService;
import someCompanyThings.INlsKey;

/**
 * A Chart with vertical or horizontal bars. It is assumed that the Bars represent positive integer numbers. 
 * Data may be added or removed dynamically but on the first intent it should display static.
 */
public class MyBarChart extends GridPane implements IMyBarChart {

/*
 * Due to data binding problems with a generic bar chart, we hold the two possible bar charts as member variables.
 * Also each of them get's a list of Series<?, ?> 
 */
private BarChart<String, Number> _barChartVertical;

private BarChart<Number, String> _barChartHorizontal;

private final ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> _dataVertical = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private final ObservableList<Series<Number, String>> _dataHorizontal = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private long _maxValue = 0;

private boolean _numberAxisInPercent = false;

private boolean _horizontal = false;



public MyBarChart(INlsKey pTitle, INlsKey pXLabel, INlsKey pYLabel, boolean pNumberAxisInPercent, boolean pHorizontal) {
    super();
    CategoryAxis categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    categoryAxis.setId("bar-chart-category-axis");

    NumberAxis numberAxis = new NumberAxis(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    numberAxis.setId("bar-chart-number-axis");

    // create bar chart
    // horizontal means that the x-axis is a number axis and the y-axis is a category axis
    if (pHorizontal) {
        categoryAxis.setLabel(LocaleService.getMessage(pYLabel));
        numberAxis.setLabel(LocaleService.getMessage(pXLabel));
        _barChartHorizontal = new BarChart<Number, String>(numberAxis, categoryAxis);
        _barChartHorizontal.setData(_dataHorizontal);
        _barChartHorizontal.setTitle(LocaleService.getMessage(pTitle));
        getChildren().add(_barChartHorizontal);
    }
    else {
        categoryAxis.setLabel(LocaleService.getMessage(pXLabel));
        numberAxis.setLabel(LocaleService.getMessage(pYLabel));
        _barChartVertical = new BarChart<String, Number>(categoryAxis, numberAxis);
        _barChartVertical.setData(_dataVertical);
        _barChartVertical.setTitle(LocaleService.getMessage(pTitle));
        getChildren().add(_barChartVertical);
    }

    _numberAxisInPercent = pNumberAxisInPercent;
    _horizontal = pHorizontal;

    /*
     * layout
     */
    setHgrow(getChildren().get(0), Priority.ALWAYS);
    setVgrow(getChildren().get(0), Priority.ALWAYS);

}



@Override
public IMyBarChart addSeries(INlsKey pSeriesName, ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> pDataSet) {
    final Series<String, Number> series = new Series<String, Number>(LocaleService.getMessage(pSeriesName), pDataSet);
    _dataVertical.add(series);

    // iterate over the whole data segment and add it to the series
    for (final Data<String, Number> data : pDataSet) {
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.setText(data.getXValue());
        Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), tooltip);

        if (data.getYValue().longValue() > _maxValue) {
            _maxValue = data.getYValue().longValue();
        }
    }

    setNumberAxisScale();

    return this;
}



@Override
public IMyBarChart addSeriesHorizontal(INlsKey pSeriesName, ObservableList<Data<Number, String>> pDataSet) {
    final Series<Number, String> series = new Series<Number, String>(LocaleService.getMessage(pSeriesName), pDataSet);
    _dataHorizontal.add(series);

    // iterate over the whole data segment and add it to the series
    for (final Data<Number, String> data : pDataSet) {
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.setText(data.getYValue());
        Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), tooltip);

        if (data.getXValue().longValue() > _maxValue) {
            _maxValue = data.getXValue().longValue();
        }
    }

    setNumberAxisScale();

    return this;
}



private void setNumberAxisScale() {
    NumberAxis numberAxis = getNumberAxis();
    // set the number axis as a percent axis
    if (_numberAxisInPercent) {
        numberAxis.setUpperBound(100);
        numberAxis.setTickUnit(10);
    }
    else {
        numberAxis.setUpperBound(_maxValue + 1);
        numberAxis.setTickUnit(1);
    }
}



@Override
public void setLegendVisible(boolean pVisible) {
    if (_barChartHorizontal != null) {
        _barChartHorizontal.setLegendVisible(pVisible);
    }
    else {
        _barChartVertical.setLegendVisible(pVisible);
    }
}



@Override
public void setCategories(ObservableList<String> pCategories) {
    getCategoryAxis().getCategories().setAll(pCategories);
}



/**
 * 
 * @return the category axis of the used bar chart
 */
private CategoryAxis getCategoryAxis() {
    if (_horizontal) {
        return (CategoryAxis)_barChartHorizontal.getYAxis();
    }
    else {
        return (CategoryAxis)_barChartVertical.getXAxis();
    }
}



/**
 * 
 * @return the number axis of the used bar chart
 */
private NumberAxis getNumberAxis() {
    if (_horizontal) {
        return (NumberAxis)_barChartHorizontal.getXAxis();
    }
    else {
        return (NumberAxis)_barChartVertical.getYAxis();
    }
}

}
```

The initialization process:

```
final IMyBarChart tablespacesChart = MyFactory.createBarChart(NlsKeys.tablespacesTitle, NlsKeys.tablespacesXAxis,
            NlsKeys.tablespacesYAxis, true, true); 
// first bool -> numberAxisInPercent, second bool -> horizontal ortientation
    tablespacesChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    tablespacesChart.setCategories(model.getListCategories());
    tablespacesChart.addSeriesHorizontal(NlsKeys.tablespacesLegendYAxis, model.getListDataUsedMax());
```

The data changes are realised by another class that just uses

```
model.getCategories().setAll(MyNewCatList); // or
model.getListDataUsedMax().setAll(MyNewList);
```

Well, i also tried to implement the chart with just one member variable (like BarChart _barChart) but this didn't work.
Now i have those layout issues and i dunno where they come from. So i hope you can give me a hint :-)

Comment: I solved the problem by deactivating the charts animation (setAnimated(false);)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:
First, create a subclass of bar chart to access the private method updateAxisRange:

```
class MyBarChart<X, Y> extends BarChart<X, Y> {

    public MyBarChart(Axis xAxis, Axis yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    public void relayout() {
        updateAxisRange();
    }

}
```

Next, instantiate your bar chart as MyBarChart:

```
MyBarChart<String, Number> barChart = new MyBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
```

And Lastly, you need to listen to resize events on the parent containing the chart, and when they occur, invoke the relayout of the chart.
For example:

```
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(barChart);
pane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2)   {
            barChart.relayout();
        }
    });
```